# Javers Mongo collections are not initialized on startup

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, javers

I am using Javers 6.5.3 with MongoDB with transactions. When I am trying to commit changes in Javers I have got an error:

`Cannot create namespace jv_snapshots in multi-document transaction`

To fix it I have to manually create `jv_snapshots` and `jv_head_id` collections in my database, but I am loosing all the indexes and stuff from Javers `MongoSchemaManager`

I was trying to add `@EnableMongoRepositories({"org.javers.spring.repository"})` in config file as shown in documentation but it does not work.

How to force Javers to create collections on start up?

Thank you

Comment: Did you followed https://javers.org/documentation/spring-boot-integration/#Javers-MongoDB-Repository ?

Comment: I did. Do you have something specific in mind?

Comment: integration withe MongoSchemaManager is a new feature , there might be a bug . If you can reproduce please contribute a failing test case , see https://github.com/javers/javers/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#guidelines-for-bug-reporting